# Cancel current co routine kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

How do i cancel the current co routine if the current coroutine is active ?
Here is the code

```
fun coRoutine2(interval: Long) {
    val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
    if (coroutineScope.isActive) {
        coroutineScope.cancel()
    } else {
        coroutineScope.launch {
            for (i in 1..progressBar.max) {
                delay(interval)
                progressBar.progress = i
                println(i)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to cancel couroutine you should cancel the `Job` object returned when you call `launch` method

```
val job = coroutineScope.launch {
            for (i in 1..progressBar.max) {
                delay(interval)
                progressBar.progress = i
                println(i)
            }
        }
job.cancel()
```

see more examples in [official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/cancellation-and-timeouts.html)